# What is the best database CRUD technique available in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, dynamic-data, crud

I know I can poll the database in my code behind and construct an HTML interface to Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) records in my database. However, I am looking to save some time and start off with the best available technique(s).

Dynamic Data looks promising as well as OData coupled with WCF and JQuery grid(s). How mature is this approach?

Time wise, Dynamic Data looks like the fastest. I imagine its quite rigid for the same reason. Is it?

Are there other recommended techniques/frameworks?

Comment: Voting off topic.  [See the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "I use ______ for ______, what do you use?"

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Data is certainly not rigid.  You can do just about everything you'd want around a CRUD-type application.  Basically, it's just a hybrid of some ASP.NET Forms techniques on top of an ASP.NET MVC framework.  It lays out templates for editing every type of data type.  It then builds forms for all the entities you expose to it.  You can have a site up and running in 5 minutes.  You can then customize the different templates provided and the style, or just add totally new pages and logic.

Comment: Sounds more flexible than I thought. I will give it a try and see how I do. Thanks

Comment: OData is the new way but I think in a lot of ways they've complicated things too much.  Dynamic Data is definitely more beginner friendly.  The articles on it are kind of old, but you should be ok just creating a new project, adding an Entity Framework model, and following the comments in Global.asax.  Then, just explore/change the generated templates to get an idea of how it all works.